# Single-Window Mode for multiple worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, single-instance

Is it possible in Microsoft Excel 2013+ (the plus currently means 2016 too) to open multiple sheets in the very same work space? Basically View=>Split but for different worksheets.

The reason I ask is because when I put multiple sheets besides each other I can't use alt+tab to see both windows. I have to re-arrange them every time I go to a non Excel window and then go back.

Comment: Yes, they each have a set of icons on the top right, below the application's. Just use those to resize them each in the workspace.

Answer (score -1):

#### Is it possible open multiple worksheets in the same workspace?

You can view multiple worksheets using the instructions below.

---

#### View two or more worksheets at the same time

> **View two worksheets in the same workbook side by side**
>
> 1. On the View tab, in the Window group, click New Window.
>
>    [image: The Window group on the View tab]
> 2. On the View tab, in the Window group, click View Side by Side [image: Button image].
> 3. In the workbook window, click the worksheets that you want to compare.
> 4. To scroll both worksheets at the same time, click Synchronous Scrolling [image: Synchronous Scrolling] in the Window group on the View tab.
>
>    Note: This option is available only when View Side by Side is turned
>      on.
>
> Tips
>
> - If you resize the workbook windows for optimal viewing, you can click Reset Window Position [Button image](https://osiprodweuodcspstoa01.blob.core.windows.net/en-us/media/33403ed3-ec76-4b92-b2d3-bb4e09856eb8.gif) to return to the original
>     settings.
> - To restore a workbook window to full size, click Maximize [image] at the upper-right corner of the workbook window.
>
> **View multiple worksheets at the same time**
>
> 1. Open the workbook or workbooks that contain the worksheets that you want to view at the same time.
> 2. Do one of the following:
>
>    If the worksheets that you want to view are in the same workbook, do
>      the following:
>
>    - Click a worksheet that you want to view.
>    - On the View tab, in the Window group, click New Window.
>
>      [image]
>    - Repeat steps 1 and 2 for each sheet that you want to view.
>
>    If the worksheets that you want to view are in different workbooks,
>      continue with step 3.
> 3. On the View tab, in the Window group, click Arrange All.
> 4. Under Arrange, click the option that you want.
> 5. To view sheets only in the active workbook, select the Windows of active workbook check box.
>
> Tip
>
> - To restore a workbook window to full size, click Maximize [image] at the upper-right corner of the workbook window.

Source [View two or more worksheets at the same time](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/View-two-or-more-worksheets-at-the-same-time-2892a172-8d6f-48e6-92fb-351b91a4dd3a)

Comment: Yes, but like I wrote "when I put multiple sheets besides each other I can't use alt+tab to see both windows. I have to re-arrange them every time I go to a non Excel window and then go back."